# It's not abstract does not override abstract method

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

Why am I getting this compile error message from the code below?

(The program moves an arrow round in 4 directions depending on which arrow key is pressed
 on the keyboard:d)

> Direction.java:41: error: DirectionPanel.DirectionListener is not
>   abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(KeyEvent)
>   in KeyListener

```
private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener  {

    //Direction.java

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;

    class DirectionPanel extends JPanel  {

      private final int WIDTH = 300, HEIGHT = 200;
      private final int JUMP = 10; //increment for image movement
      private final int IMAGE_SIZE = 31;
      private ImageIcon up, down, right, left, currentImage;
      private int x, y;

      //constructor:
      public DirectionPanel ()  {

      addKeyListener (new DirectionListener());
      x =WIDTH / 2;
      y = HEIGHT / 2;
      up = new ImageIcon ("arrowUp.gif");
      down = new ImageIcon ("arrowDown.gif");
      left = new ImageIcon ("arrowLeft.gif");
      right = new ImageIcon ("arrowRight.gif");

      currentImage = right;

      setBackground (Color.black);
      setPreferredSize (new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
      setFocusable(true);
      }

      //draws
      public void paintComponent (Graphics page)  {
        super.paintComponent (page);
        currentImage.paintIcon (this, page, x, y);
      }

      //represents the listener for keyboard activity
      private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener  {
        public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)  {
          switch (event.getKeyCode())  {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                currentImage = up;
                y -= JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                currentImage = down;
                y += JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                currentImage = left;
                x -= JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                currentImage = right;
                x += JUMP;
                break;
          }
        repaint();
        }
      //empty definitions for unused methods
      private void KeyTyped (KeyEvent event) {}
      private void KeyReleased (KeyEvent event) {}

      }
    }


    public class Direction  {

      public static void main (String[] args)  {

      JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Direction");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add (new DirectionPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    }
```

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? It's pretty clear. Character case matters in Java, but also you can't reduce the visibility of a method.

Comment: Ahaha you are very 'on the ball' Sotirios :D I have it compiled now but I dont know what you mean by 'reduce the visibility of a method' -Also though (i should probably start a new question for this) it compiles now, when i run it, I and I click my mouse on the black screen I cant see anything. Is there something else wrong with the code or is it a problem with my mouse because it happened with the last GUI project I tried as well.

Comment: If the interface declares a method as `public`, you can't make it `private` in a sub type.

Comment: Ok i made keyTyped and keyReleased pulic

Answer (score 10):

The error meesage is

```
DirectionPanel.DirectionListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener private class DirectionListener implements KeyListener
```

So obviously your class does not override all the methods it needs to, for example `keyReleased`. If you look at your class, you have `KeyReleased` and it's `private`.

Rename these

```
private void KeyTyped (KeyEvent event) {}
private void KeyReleased (KeyEvent event) {}
```

to `keyTyped` and `keyReleased` (note the lowercase `k`) and make them `public` since Java doesn't allow sub types to reduce the visibility of an overriden method. Then annotate each with `@Override`.

Annotating a method with `@Override` causes a compile error if it doesn't actually override. [Section 9.6.1.4 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html) says:

> The annotation type Override supports early detection of such problems. If a method declaration is annotated with the annotation @Override, but the method does not in fact override any method declared in a superclass, a compile-time error will occur.

Comment: If an method annotated with `@Override` does *not* in fact override you get a compile error (not just a "hint")

Comment: Ok thanks guys. Ive got it compiled now. Just can't see the arrow on the panel when I run it ?

Comment: @user3142706 I don't know much about swing. I can't help you in that regard.

Comment: @user3142706 this answer is correct, but take a look of my answer perhaps it helps you!

Comment: Yes. Added special sauce to your answer :)

Comment: The answer is correct but as long as it contains a Swing tag, i would personally prefer some positive direction given in perspective of swing as @nachokk(+1 to him) did. However, `KeyAdapter` is designed for this special purposes, and the listeners should be added in-line making use of Anonymous function. Hence, Sorry but i don't see your function re-naming approach as a good advice.

Comment: @Sage The code doesn't compile if they don't rename their methods.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes that is a solution but not a good advice. That is what i meant :)

Comment: @Sage I'm not giving advice. As I've said, I don't know `swing` and therefore can't comment on design. I'm simply answering `Why am I getting this compile error message from the code below?`

Comment: @Sage actually i added swing tag after this answer, this answer is fullcorrect i just append more information for this answer

Comment: @nachokk, uhh i didn't Know that. I myself said that Solitirios's answer is correct. But as i have thought that the OP himself tagged it as Swing(Which in fact you did), I do prefer your own answer (extending to *Sotirios*):)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Sotirios Delimanolis answer that is correct, you may want to take a look to use [Keybindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead of using keyListeners that has 2 big issues, it listens for all keys and components must be focusable and in focus.

Another thing (if you still want to use keyListeners) you may want to extends [KeyAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) that provide default implementation of KeyListener methods (empty methods) therefore you don't need to override methods that you don't use like `keyReleased` or `keyTyped`.

Example:

```
    private class DirectionListener extends KeyAdapter  {
       @Override 
       public void keyPressed (KeyEvent event)  {
          switch (event.getKeyCode())  {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                currentImage = up;
                y -= JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                currentImage = down;
                y += JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                currentImage = left;
                x -= JUMP;
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                currentImage = right;
                x += JUMP;
                break;
          }
        repaint();
        }
    }
```